# Search for a character in a line and append entire line to a list

Tags: python

Trying to create a dictionary file and postings list file, by finding the document ID. It should open the file and search for the term '.I' and take the line as a list element

```
#Function which find the doc ID

#There is a list I created with name idList

def idTag():

file = open('cacm.txt', 'r')

line = file.readline()

while line:

if '.I' in line:

 idList.append(line)

elif not '.I' in line:

 line = file.readline()

elif not line:

 file.close()`
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  (What isn't working?)

Comment: Please indent your code!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, but if I read the question correctly, you want to iterate over the lines of a file, filtering those which contain the string `'.I'`. Therefore, this should work:

```
def idTag():
    # Create the list to collect the results in
    idList = []
    # Better way of opening a file;
    # closes it automatically when the `with` statement is finished
    with open('cacm.txt', 'r') as file:
        # Read each line from the file
        for line in file:
            # Filter those that have `.I` in them
            if '.I' in line:
                idList.append(line)
    return line
```

This takes advantage of the fact that files can be looped over, reading a line at a time.

Comment: [line for line in file if '.I' in line] is probably the most pythonic way